# How to validate REST api params using regex in flask?

Tags: flask, flask-restful, connexion, flask-marshmallow

I am working on a REST api using flask/connexion. Consider this endpoint:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/library/{category_name}/{version}
```

category_name and version are from string type. How can I validate them with a custom regex?

I am using sqlalchemy and marshmallow for ORM and data serialization.

Comment: What are you trying to validate them for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["re"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library or [Flask-Inputs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Inputs/) extension